# Find filename from local repository with sbt

Tags: java, scala, sbt, aspectj

In SBT, I would like to add a task to start a JVM with AspectJ agent weaver. I would like to declare a dependency

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % aspectjVersion.value % "test")
```

and use the local downloaded version (like ~/.m2/.../aspecjweaver....jar) to start a forked JVM.
Something like this:

```
javaOptions "-javaagent:"+localFileFromArtifact
```

How I can retrieve the local file name from library dependencies ?

Many thanks

Comment: you can use `fullClasspath` to find dependency and retrieve `File`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy files to target so they are used in run task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239126/how-to-copy-files-to-target-so-they-are-used-in-run-task)