# How to copy files to target so they are used in run task?

Tags: sbt

I would like to copy artifact from repository to the `target` subdirectory, before invoke the special `run` task.

```
// audit task must invoke the run task, after copy artifact in some directory
audit := {
  println("In audit")
  // 1. Copy some artifact to directory
 val auditAgent = ((fullClasspath in Test value) filter (_.data.getName.startsWith("reactive-audit-agent"))).head.data
 val targetAgent= target.value / "reactive-audit-libs" / "reactive-audit-agent.jar"
 IO.copyFile(auditAgent,targetAgent)

  // 2. Set javaOpt. Something like this
 javaOptions += "-javagent:"+targetAgent

  // 3. Invoke run task with javaagent
  ???

}
```

With `sbt run` I would like to run the project.
With `sbt audit` I would like to run the project with a specific javagent.

I try to use `fullRunTask(audit,...)` to extend the `audit` task, but the body in `audit` was not running

```
audit := {
  println("In audit")
}

fullRunTask(audit, Runtime, "com.octo.reactive.sample.TestApp")
```

Comment: Is the artefact from a repository required to run the task? Is the file a part of the project itself, but sits in a non-standard directory? sbt is a build tool and however it's possible to do what you're asking it seems it's not really a part of a build.

Comment: I would like to publish a tool in maven repository. Then, I would like to propose a sbt script to run the program with this tools. It'a a java agent.
So, I would like to copy the file from the repository to a temporary directory, and custom the javaOption to run the audit with the tool.

Comment: It appears that the tool in maven repo is a dependency of the project. Why don't you declare it as such and have it handled by sbt?! Even if it's a custom "configuration" in a project, others who work on the project would love knowing about the "hack". Create a custom configuration in sbt and add the dependency to it.

Comment: Ok. Now, I can copy the jar to invoke the agent. But, I can't run the task AND the body in audit task with fullRunTask :-(

Comment: Can you do **UPDATE** to your question and show where you're at and what is missing. It's going to be tough to help you otherwise.

Comment: How about my recent update with custom configuration with update? Would that get us closer to a final solution?

Comment: Done. Is it more clear ?

Comment: Thanks. Do you need anything more for the question since you've approved the answer?

Comment: You answer help me to resolve the problem to copy file, but not to running a task. The source code explain what I would like to do. 1) copy some file, 2) Update javaOptions, 3) run the project with this javaOptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62764/discussion-between-jacek-laskowski-and-pprados).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Custom configuration with update report

Based upon [Configurations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Configurations) and [Update Report](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Update-Report.html) I've figured out another approach to declare a dependency and use it in a task. This approach explicitly declares a dependency on an external file that's required for a task, say to become a java agent.

What I seem to have missed in the past revisions of the answer was the requirement:

> With `sbt run` I would like to run the project. With `sbt audit` I would like to run the project with a specific javagent.

The following `build.sbt` gives a solution (it assumes sbt 0.13.7-M3 with [the change for no blank lines](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1606) - add blank lines if you don't want to upgrade yet):

```
lazy val Agent = config("agent") extend Runtime

inConfig(Agent)(Defaults.configSettings)
sourceDirectory in Agent <<= sourceDirectory in Compile

ivyConfigurations += Agent

// that makes the file available in the Ivy2 local repository
libraryDependencies += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.2" % "agent"

fork in (Agent, run) := true

javaOptions in (Agent, run) += 
  "-javaagent:" + update.value.select(configurationFilter("agent")).filter(_.name.contains("aspectjweaver")).head

addCommandAlias("audit", "agent:run")
```

The build defines a new hidden `agent` configuration with a dependency that belongs to the configuration only.

Using `update` (as described in [Update Report](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Update-Report.html)) I could select just the declared dependency as the "agent" for `run`, but since the configuration `extend Runtime` I had to exclude the other "transitive" dependencies (that `Runtime` gives).

When you execute `run` it runs the good old `run` task - no changes here:

```
> run
[info] Running com.example.Hello
Hello, world!
```

When you run `agent:run` it executes the custom `run` in `Agent` configuration (you see no change unless you change - make a typo in - `-javaagent` to something else that ultimately breaks the startup):

```
> agent:run
[info] Running com.example.Hello
[info] Hello, world!
```

As the final solution there's the `audit` alias that's effectively `agent:run`.

```
> audit
[info] Running com.example.Hello
[info] Hello, world!
```

With the solution sbt downloads the dependency as usual (so we don't have to worry if the file exists or not and when it does not, the build will simply fail).

### Copying files to directory using resource generators

> How I can copy some files to a directory, before run the project ?

Read the page [Generating files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html) where you find the section [Generate resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#resources) that says:

> A resource generation task should generate resources in a subdirectory of resourceManaged and return a sequence of files generated.

Do `show resourceManaged` to find out the path that's by default under `target/scala-[scalaVersion]`.